# how to build such a Android app that could paste a text instead of my copied text?

Tags: android-studio, clipboard.js

How can I build a App on Android which will be capable of paste a different text instead of a specified Text I copied from any where.

example : I will copy a text like "Cat"
My app will change "Cat" & paste "Dog" instead of "Cat"  (when cat is a specified text)

I have much idea on c and c# just give me any possible suggestion,  i'll built it my self.

Comment: I'm unsure what is the goal here. How do you determine that when someone types `Cat`, it should be `Dog` ? Why not `Turtle` or `Tree` ?

Comment: I asked About Copy, Paste. But your answer & judgement is about 'typing.  . .   I am trying to mean that  If user copy something like "Orange,Banana,Grape,Apple"  together without space. At the time when user will Paste it,  the text should be Pasted as "Fruits"  .